# Ошибка в цикле, удаляющем пробелы

Tags: c++, циклы

Есть код, который выявляет, является ли фраза или слово палиндромом, есть такой код

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "locale.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"
using namespace std;

char slovo[80], prov[80] = { 0 };
int t = 0, i = 0, a, z=0, o=0;

char* netprobelam(char *slovo)
{
    do
    {
        if (slovo[z] == ' ') {
            o = z;
            z--;
            do
            {
                slovo[o] = slovo[o + 1];
            } while (slovo[o] != '\0');
        }
        z++;
    } while (slovo[z] != '\0');
    return slovo;
}

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    cin >> slovo;
    do
    {
        t++;
    } while (slovo[t] != '\0');
    a = t;
    t = a - 1;
    netprobelam(slovo);
    system("pause");
    do
    {
        prov[i] = slovo[t];
        i++;
        t--;
    } while (t != -1);
    t = 0;
    i = i - 1;
    do
    {
        t++;
        i--;
    } while (slovo[t] == prov[i]);
    if ((t - 1) == a)
    {
        cout << "Выполняется\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Не выполняется\n";
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

проблема в том, что функция не заменяет все буквы на следующие, а лишь обрубает слово до первого пробела, прошу помощи.

Comment: Глобальные переменные  - это ужасно. Особенно, когда они для счетчиков используются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cin >> slovo;
```

работает именно так - до первого пробела. Попробуйте [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

```
 getline(cin, slovo);
```

только `slovo` сделайте `string`, а не массив.

Ну, или

```
cin.getline(slovo,80);
```

если нужен именно массив.

P.S. Но, откровенно говоря, код надо бы переписывать, как говорится, от слова "совсем"...

Например, так:

```
bool isPalindrome(const char * s)
{
    for(const char * b = s, *e = b + strlen(s) - 1; b <= e; ++b, --e)
    {
        while(*b == ' ') ++b;
        while(*e == ' ') --e;
        if (*b != *e) return false;
    }
    return true;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    string s;
    getline(cin,s);
    cout << "\"" << s << "\" is "
        << (isPalindrome(s.c_str()) ? "" : "not ") << "palindrome\n";
}
```